# График Treemap в Delphi?

Tags: delphi

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть ли такой компонент Treemap плиточная диаграмма где размер плитки зависит от значения, по типу как на сайте https://finviz.com/map.ashx?t=sec
Или может есть алгоритм как это реализовать?

Comment: В Teechart Pro есть серии TreeMap. Как оно на практике - не знаю. `Treemaps display hierarchical (tree-structured) data as a set of nested rectangles. Each branch of the tree is given a rectangle, which is then 
tiled 
with smaller rectangles representing sub-branches. A leaf node's rectangle has an area proportional to a specified dimension on the data. 
(Description from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treemapping)

In specific Add method override, AValue represent node's value, Text represents node's text and Superior node's parent.`

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ! А есть ли бесплатный вариант?

Comment: С Дельфи поставляется тичарт без про, там такой серии может и не быть.